# Fitting an autoregressive models not using the classical Maximum Likelihood Estimator?

Tags: machine-learning, autocorrelation, gaussian-process, autoregressive, lstm

I know for example, one could try the Recurrent Neural Networks approaches. But are there any other options to these? I don't know if the questions is rather absurd.

I am thinking of models like either Decision Trees, Gaussian Processes, or any other Machine Learning alternatives.

I am wondering if one could do something similar to $VAR(p)$, Distributed lag models, or $ARIMA(p,d,q)$ using other techniques. Therefore being able to do the functional relationship $Y_{t}  \sim f(X_{t-1}, X_{t-2}, Y_{t-1}, Y_{t-2})$.

On other note I would like to know if it is absolutely necessary that the assumptions of the "equidistance" are necessary for the $Y_{t}$. E.g: there is a very specific behavior that happened and at that moment $Y_{t}, Y_{t-1}, Y_{t-2}$ were studied, but only $Y_{t}$ will be used as response and the similar phenomena happened again n ($n \in N $, n can be random) minutes later. Would it be wrong to see it from an auto-regressive perspective?

I ask it since if one thinks of the LSTM perspective, the input would be
`tensor([input_size, 2, 2])`, having 2 features and 2 timesteps. But I am not sure if during the optimization process there is an interaction of the $Y_{t}$ used as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be confusing models with estimators. ARIMA and VAR are models. A neural network or a decision tree (or forest) can also be interpreted as a model. Meanwhile, maximum likelihood or ordinary least squares are estimation techniques. They are used to estimate a model's parameters. (And then there are optimization routines like gradient descent or simulated annealing. They facilitate estimators by providing a numerical solution to an estimator's equation.)

You seem to be interested in models. Indeed, you can model $Y_t$ as a function of its lags $Y_{t-1},Y_{t-2},...$. An autoregression provides a linear model with a finite number of lags. An ARIMA can in many cases be represented as an autoregression with an infinite number of lags (but still linear). A neural network or a tree-based model is a nonlinear model (normally with a finite number of lags). You can absolutely try that. There is no reason for a linear model to necessarily outperform a nonlinear one on all time series; there are certainly cases where nonlinear models can do better.

Regarding your second question, it is quite distinct from the first one, so I suggest you cut it from this post and post it separately on a new thread.

Comment: I think in my head I didn't have the confusion but couldn't exactly show it with words. My bad! I have fitted the linear models but I recently because of the data particularities I only have specific time frames with enough data to fit a $VAR(p)$ or a Distributed Lag Model. Actually, because of that, I am more interested in question two. But indeed, probably I should ask it separately. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierJaraÁvila, you are welcome! Once you post your second question separately, remember to come back here and remove it from this thread. Thanks!